# Converting Task<A> to Task<B> asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, task

I'm integrating internal authentication service with MembershipProvider. Custom provider:

```
    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(
        string username,
        string password,
        string email,
        string passwordQuestion,
        string passwordAnswer,
        bool isApproved,
        object providerUserKey,
        out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {

        //var res = client.Register(username, password, email);
        //status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success; // conver to Mem
        return null;
```

Problem is in the client. **How to convert one task to another?**

```
    public async Task<MembershipUser> Register(string username, string password, string email, bool isStaff=false)
    {
        var task = serviceFoo.Register(username, password, email, isStaff);
        // TODO Task<RegisteredUser> -> Task<MembershipUser>
        //var convertedTask = task.
        //return new Task<MembershipUser>();
    }
```

I want to:

- do it asynchronously
- I don't want RegisteredUser to be visible for provider.

I will write an extension method for RegUser for conversation, but I have no idea how to convert task asynchronously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it doesn't look like you actually want to convert from `Task<RegisteredUser>` to `Task<MembershipUser>`, you want to convert from `RegisteredUser` to `MembershipUser`, assuming you have the conversion extension method you mention, just do this:

```
public async Task<MembershipUser> Register(string username, string password, string email, bool isStaff=false)
{
        var user = await serviceFoo.Register(username, password, email, isStaff);// user is RegisteredUser
        return user.ConvertTomembershipUser();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Task doesn't have build in funtionality for composition. Fortunately, it's trivial to implement

```
public static async Task<TResult> flatmap<TSource, TResult>(this Task<TSource> src, Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> f) {
  return await f(await src);
}

public static async Task<TResult> map<TSource, TResult>(this Task<TSource> src, Func<TSource, TResult> f) {
  return f(await src);
}
```